# Access to Drools returned fact object in Java Code

Tags: java, drools, guvnor

I have a drools rule created via the Guvnor console and the rule validates and inserts a fact into the working memory if conditions were met. The rule is:

```
    1. | rule "EligibilityCheck001" 
    2. |     dialect "mvel" 
    3. |     when 
    4. |         Eligibility( XXX== "XXX" , YYY== "YYY" , ZZZ== "ZZZ" , BBB == "BBB" ) 
    5. |     then 
    6. |         EligibilityInquiry fact0 = new EligibilityInquiry(); 
    7. |         fact0.setServiceName( "ABCD" ); 
    8. |         fact0.setMemberStatus( true ); 
    9. |         insert(fact0 ); 
   10. |         System.out.println( "Hello from Drools"); 
   11. | end
```

Java code that executes the rule is as follows

```
RuleAgent ruleAgent = RuleAgent.newRuleAgent("/Guvnor.properties");
RuleBase ruleBase = ruleAgent.getRuleBase();
FactType factType = ruleBase.getFactType("mortgages.Eligibility");

Object obj = factType.newInstance();
factType.set(obj, "XXX", "XXX");
factType.set(obj, "YYY", "YYY");
factType.set(obj, "ZZZ", "XXX");
factType.set(obj, "BBB", "BBB");

WorkingMemory workingMemory = ruleBase.newStatefulSession();
workingMemory.insert(obj);
workingMemory.fireAllRules();
System.out.println("After drools execution");
long count = workingMemory.getFactCount();
System.out.println("count " + count);
```

Everything looks great with the output as below:

```
Hello from Drools
After drools execution
count 2
```

I cannot seem to find a way to get the `EligibilityInquiry` fact object back in my Java code and get the attributes set in the rule above (`serviceName` and `status`). I have used the `StatefulSession` approach.

The properties file has the link to the snapshot with basic authentication via username and password. There are 2 total facts: `EligibilityInquiry` and `Eligibility`.

I am fairly new to drools and any help with the above is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note: I fixed the order of statement, a typo ("XX") and removed the comments from the output. Less surprise.)

This snippet assumes that `EligibilityInquiry` is also declared in DRL.

```
FactType eligInqFactType = ruleBase.getFactType("mortgages", "EligibilityInquiry");
Class<?> eligInqClass = eligInqFactType.getFactClass();
ObjectFilter filter = new FilterByClass( eligInqClass );
Collection<Object> eligInqs = workingMemory.getObjects( filter );
```

And the filter is

```
public class FilterByClass implements ObjectFilter {
    private Class<?> theClass;
    public FilterByClass( Class<?> clazz ){
        theClass = clazz;
    }
    public boolean accept(Object object){
        return theClass.isInstance( object );
    } 
}
```

You might also use a `query`, which takes about the same amount of code.

```
// DRL code
query "eligInqs" 
    eligInq : EligibilityInquiry()
end

// after return from fireAllRules
QueryResults results = workingMemory.getQueryResults( "eligInqs" );
for ( QueryResultsRow row : results ) {
    Object eligInqObj = row.get( "eligInq" );
    System.out.println( eligInqClass.cast( eligInqObj ) );
}
```

Or you can call `workingMemory.getObjects()` and iterate the collection and check for the class of each object.

```
for( Object obj: workingMemory.getObjects() ){
    if( obj.isInstance( eligInqClass ) ){
        System.out.println( eligInqClass.cast( eligInqObj ) );
    }
}
```

Or you can (with or without inserting the created EligibilityInquiry object as a fact) add the fact to a `global java.util.List eligInqList` and iterate that in your Java code. Note that the API of `StatefulKnowledgeSession` is required (instead of `WorkingMemory`).

```
   // Java - prior to fireAllRules
   StatefulKnowledgeSession kSession() = ruleBase.newStatefulSession();

   List<?> list = new ArrayList();
   kSession.setGlobal( "eligInqList", list );

   // DRL
   global java.util.List eligInqList;

   // in a rule
   then
       EligibilityInquiry fact0 = new EligibilityInquiry(); 
       fact0.setServiceName( "ABCD" ); 
       fact0.setMemberStatus( true ); 
       insert(fact0 );  
       eligInqList.add( fact0 ); 
   end

   // after return from fireAllRules
   for( Object elem: list ){
    System.out.println( eligInqClass.cast( elem ) );
   }
```

Probably an embarras de richesses.

Comment: Thanks this is very well explained for a novice .

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but for the same question, if I have to retrieve the fact0 from Drools Rule Execution Server via REST api, how do I do that?

Comment: @Dminds did you get the answer for retrieving the fact0 from Drools Rule Execution Server via REST api.

Comment: Nope @VaibhavBhootna.

Comment: I think in the third example you meant `if( obj.isInstance( eligInqClass ) )`